# printf only display 24 characters of char*

Tags: c, string, printf, malloc

I am doing a project of creating a bot that surfs the internet.

I have to code it in C and for now I'm focusing on the choice of the address where it will go (choosen from a list in a file). This works properly but when I display the addresses the bot has chosen, some are truncated to 24 characters and end with "!" which makes the code unusable with long addresses. Does anyone have any idea of where it might come?

The program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

  char *line = NULL;
  char *tab[1023];
  int tailleTab = 0;

  line = malloc(sizeof(*line));

  if(line == NULL)
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);

  while((fgets(line, 1023, file)) != NULL ) {
    if(line[0] != '#' && line[0] != '\n') {
      tab[tailleTab] = line;
      line = malloc(sizeof(*line));
      tailleTab++;
    }
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  int n = rand()%tailleTab;
  printf("\n%d = %.32s\n", n, tab[n]);
  printf("%s\n", tab[n]);
  fclose(file);
}
```

The file from which the address is chosen:

```
www.google.com
www.wikipedia.org
www.dahunicorn.xyz
www.cloudimperiumgames.com
www.robertspaceindustries.com
www.candybox2.net
www.42.com
www.1337.com
```

Comment: Share your input please - there's no way for us to guess it!!! Also, please share your debugging observation.

Comment: Please free allocations after using them. Good habit to also do this in simple test snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this:

```
line = malloc(sizeof(*line));
```

This only allocates a *single* character to `line`. The expression `*line` is a `char` which means you allocate `sizeof(char)` bytes, and `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be `1`.

That means your call to `fgets` will write out of bounds of your allocated memory and you will have *undefined behavior*.

There's no reason to actually allocate `line` dynamically. Instead create it as an array, and then use `strdup` when saving it in the `tab` array. Either that or allocate more memory (`1023` is a good number, since that's amount you pass to `fgets`).

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in another answer, with this code:

> ```
> line = malloc(sizeof(*line));
> ```

you are allocating with `malloc` a single `char` on the heap, since the expression `*line` is equivalent to a `char` (as `line` is declared as `char *`).

I would simplify your code using named constants instead of *magic numbers* like `1023` that are spread through code (and make it harder to maintain), in addition to just reserving space for the temporary `line` buffer on the stack instead of dynamically allocating it on the heap, e.g.:

```
/* Instead of: line = malloc(sizeof(*line)); */
#define LINE_MAX_SIZE 1024
char line[LINE_MAX_SIZE];
```

Also consider doing:

```
#define TAB_MAX_ITEMS /* 1023 or whatever */
char* tab[TAB_MAX_ITEMS];
```

In the `while` loop consider using `LINE_MAX_SIZE` instead of the magic number `1023`:

```
while ((fgets(line, LINE_MAX_SIZE, file)) != NULL ) {
```

You may also want to add a check to the index in the `tab` array, to avoid buffer overruns:

```
if (tailleTab >= TAB_MAX_ITEMS) {
    /* Index out of range */
    ...
}

/* tailleTab is a valid index.
 * Deep-copy the line read in the temporary buffer
 * and save a pointer to the copy into the tab array.
 */
tab[tailleTab] = strdup(line);
```

In production code you should also loop through the pointers stored in the `tab` array, and call `free` on the them to release the memory allocated on the heap.